# increment progress for upload progress

Tags: flutter

I'm receiving progress from a callback and adding an event like this:

Data/Bloc

```
onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
                  var progress = sent / total;
                  this.add(ProgressUpdate(progress));
                },
```

The progress is too fast for the animation in my ui.

UI

```
child: CircularPercentIndicator(
                  radius: 130.0,
                  animation: true,
                  animationDuration: 1200,
                  lineWidth: 15.0,
                  percent:state.progress, //Percent value between 0.0 and 1.0
                  center: new Text(
                    "Loading",
                    style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
                  ),
                  circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.butt,
                  backgroundColor: AppTheme.backgroundColor,
                  progressColor: AppTheme.darkOrange,
                ),
```

wondering what's the best way to increment the response in intervals of 10 ?

Comment: do you want to update the progress in intervals of 10 seconds (ie every 10 seconds) or in intervals of 10 percents (every 10 percent of progress)?

Comment: 10 percent intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an access to the current value (as in case of `ValueStream` from `rxdart`) you could do something like this:

```dart
void main() {
  var currentIncrement = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    final increment = i ~/ 10;
    if(increment > currentIncrement) {
      currentIncrement = increment;
      print('Progress updated! ${currentIncrement * 10}%');
    }
  }
}
```

Prints:

```
Progress updated! 10%
Progress updated! 20%
Progress updated! 30%
Progress updated! 40%
Progress updated! 50%
Progress updated! 60%
Progress updated! 70%
Progress updated! 80%
Progress updated! 90%
Progress updated! 100%
```

in your case it'd look similarly to this (I haven't compiled it, so it will need some tweaking):

```dart
onSendProgress: (sent, total) {
  final progress = (sent / total * 100) ~/ 10;

  if (progress > currentValue) {
    this.add(ProgressUpdate(progress));
  }
}
```

breakdown:

- `sent / total` - fraction that represents a progress, e.g. 0.32 for 32%
- `sent / total * 100` - an actual percentage, e.g. 32%
- `~/ 10` this one divides a number discarding any fractions, so if you do `32 ~/ 10` you will get `3`

Comment: thanks not sure where to get currentValue (or what it is)...  `(progress > currentValue)`

Comment: as for the first part, I can't really help you because that depends on library you're using. I've also added an explanation of `progress`